# How this executable is able to locate this shared library invisible to ldconfig?

Tags: shared-library

I have an executable `vimba`, which uses a shared library `libVmbC.so`, which is not installed to the standard location. The copies reside at:

```
paul@desktop:~/st-cpp/vimba/build$ sudo find / -name "libVmbC.so"
/home/paul/VimbaX_2023-4/api/lib/libVmbC.so
/home/paul/VimbaX_2023-4/bin/libVmbC.so
```

On a new Ubuntu 23.10 installation, I added it to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and everything works fine. On the "old" Ubuntu 22.04 system, this library is not on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` path, which is empty:

```
paul@desktop:~/st-cpp/vimba/build$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

nor it's detected by `ldconfig`:

```
paul@desktop:~/st-cpp/vimba/build$ ldconfig -p | grep libVmbC.so
```

nor it is listed in `ld.so.conf` or any of the files included by it. `ldd` is able to locate it and `vimba` runs fine, though:

```
paul@desktop:~/st-cpp/vimba/build$ ldd vimba
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd179a3000)
    libtbb.so.12 => /usr/local/lib/libtbb.so.12 (0x00007f23bb448000)
    libVmbC.so => /home/paul/VimbaX_2023-4/api/lib/libVmbC.so (0x00007f23bb000000)
...
```

How does `ldd` know to find it at `/home/paul/VimbaX_2023-4/api/lib/libVmbC.so`?

Comment: Is [`RPATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) or `RUNPATH` set in the binary?

Comment: @muru Yes, it was: *Library runpath: [/home/paul/VimbaX_2023-4/api/lib:/usr/local/lib]*. Thank you for the link. I didn't know about RPATH. The new system has a different username, which prevented RPATH from working. If post your comment as an answer, I will accept it as a solution.

Comment: It's covered well in the answer there and in the duplicate target of that question